# Fixed IP Address for Cloud Foundry Apps

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have a PHP Cloud Foundry Apps installed.

But when I deploy new code (with cf push ), the app gets a new public IP address.

Is it possible to get a fixed public IP address, so that after a new deployment the IP address doesn't change?

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Foundry application cannot specify a fixed IP address for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry provides a route to the application via either the manifest.yml file ('host' or 'hosts' attribute) or the '-n' option to the cf push command.

Why do you need a fixed IP address?

Comment: On the another system i check, by iptables, from which machine the request are comming from.