# How to whitelist Swisscom PaaS domain/api for remote access

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am about to create a small web application which I might deploy to Swisscom PaaS as well.

This should be able to call a Rest API on a remote server.

Remote Server requires all incoming requests to be whitelisted by IP/domain.

Is it enough to whitelist ***.scapp.io** or **myapp.scapp.io** when myapp deployed on Swisscom PaaS should be able to access remote API or is it required to use a different domain/IP due to the nature how PaaS is setup and running?

Comment: for further reference I found a similar question after answer was provided valid for cloud foundry here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989559/fixed-ip-address-for-cloud-foundry-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the source IP of Swisscom Application Cloud Public offering with those commands:

```
$ cf ssh APP_NAME
$ curl ifconfig.co
194.209.246.112
# example for developer.swisscom.com
```

This IP doesn't resolve to any domain name. This IP may change / not yet stable. Since the beginning of Application Cloud (more than 3 years the IP didn't change). This is the outgoing IP to whitelist in remote app.

You raised a very good point about stable IP address pool. We consider that and will document the IPs when implemented.

Comment: hm, that's definitely not what I was expecting here. will accept the answer as it's responding to my question but I really hope you can solve this soon.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's much better, kind of expected a 'daily' change from my initial understanding.